Diagonalizing a real symmetric matrix with an orthogonal matrix
$$mt1 = \pmatrix{a& b& c\\b& d& e\\c& e&h}$$
For $mt1^T.mt2.mt1$ = d, where mt1 is an orthogonal matrix, mt2 is a real symmetric matrix and d is a diagonal matrix with eigenvalues of mt2 on the diagonal. How to find mt1 such that it is orthogonal and contains three variables using Mathematica. Any suggestion is appreciated!

This is true if mt1 is a matrix of eigenvectors of mt2. However, why do you think this is true for an arbitrary orthogonal matrix?

@DanielHuber: Check the edits.

mt1 is found via Eigensystem. This in turn can be parametrized by the coefficients of the characteristic polynomial of mt2. These are found as `In[362]:= coeffs =
Rest[Reverse[CoefficientList[-CharacteristicPolynomial[m, t], t]]]
Out[362]= {-a - d - h, -b^2 - c^2 + a d - e^2 + a h + d h,
c^2 d - 2 b c e + a e^2 + b^2 h - a d h}`

@DanielLichtblau: Can you please write this as a proper answer in the following?

Actually I'm finding I can only represent the d values in this way.

You can use Eigensystem
In the following ev is the desired matrix. I leave it to the user to choose how to express and use ev. You can use ToRadical for Root objects.
I will not print ev as it rather ugly.
The following finds ev and confirms orthogonal.
m = {{a, b, c}, {b, d, e}, {c, e, h}};
{val, ev} = {DiagonalMatrix[#1], Transpose[#2]} & @@ Eigensystem[m];
ev . Inverse[ev] // FullSimplify

yields: {{1, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 1}}

orthogonal and "contains three variables"

@SciJewel thank you. I think you need more constraints (that you have not specified). As such I cannot offer more advice than to try and give us updates
